# QT "Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" "

Tags: qt, ubuntu-18.04

I installed QT-everywhere 5.15 open-source for academic reasons, but I have failed to run a program.

Firstly, I compiled the necessary source files with `make` and installed the QT Creator, then I selected qmake for running programs inside it. When I tried to run an example program, I encounter this error:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu"
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc.
The program has unexpectedly finished.
The process was ended forcefully.
```

Then I looked into `/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu` for finding the xcb plugin and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86-64-linux-gnu`, but again the same error appeared.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You could try to set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 for more information. Do you have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so`? This is where it is supposed to be.

Comment: Yes, there is a file that has the name libqxcb.so. I also made QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1, nothing changed.

Comment: You didn't get extra output on the console with the QT_DEBUG... environment variable set?

Comment: Terminal says there is not such a command. I do not know, somewhere I can make something wrong.

Comment: @Voursstreds execute `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 /path/your/app` on console. It would also be nice to point out the command you used to compile Qt

Comment: When I change the QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms, I receive another error that is longer to read

Comment: @eyllanesc What is an app actually? There are plugins that inside the ./qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/qtbase/plugins , where should I point?

Comment: @Voursstreds You say: *When I tried to run an example program, I encounter with a problem saying this* then app is *example program*

Comment: Your Qt is not looking for the plugin path incorrectly, with which qmake have you compiled your example program? The correct qmake must be inside  `qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/`. Have you compiled the Qt? Since Qt 5.15 if you want to use the free version of Qt you must compile using the source code, it is not enough to unzip the source code

Comment: I firstly downloaded and compiled the program myself, I found a file that is named qmake in qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/qtbase/, then I chosed it for compiling the programs. I looked again the folder qt-everywhere-src-5.15.0/ , but I could not see the necessary program. I can edit my question with an image showing what I done. Compiling this code with make -j 4 takes 55 minutes, therefore it is not easy to compile again and again. If there is an error in my program, I would learn whether there is a problem that requires recompiling the whole program. @eyllanesc

Comment: In case you try to run your program as root and get the error "Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified", consider also [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/why-cant-i-run-gui-apps-from-root-no-protocol-specified).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1. Install requirements:**

```
sudo apt install make g++ pkg-config libgl1-mesa-dev libxcb*-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev python libgtk-3-dev
```

- `python` is optional for `QtQuick`.
- `libgtk-3-dev` optional if you want the GTK native theme for `QtWidgets`.

**2. Configure:**

```
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -nomake tests -nomake examples -prefix /path/to/install/dir
```

**3. Compile:**

```
make -j $(nproc)

make install
```

Comment: It's easy to forget the XCB packages if you build Qt on a new machine. I didn't get a single error during the build, either. For reference, here's an extensive list of commands to get XCB packages on various distros (see the *"Libxcb"* section): https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git#Linux.2FX11

Comment: Note: After installing the XCB dependencies, you have to re-run `configure` and add the `-recheck` argument.  Its output should say `XCB Xlib ... yes`.