# telegram bot exec GUI application on linux

Tags: python, qt, telegram-bot

I want to create telegram bot which would grab youtube link from message and play this video via smplayer on my computer (arch linux with KDE)
I created simple bot on python, than I tried to exec any GUI application by this command
`os.system('/usr/bin/smplayer')` and got this error

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
Oct 01 19:07:00 server smplayer[1961896]: qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
Oct 01 19:07:00 server smplayer[1961896]: This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application
Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland...
```

May be you know how to solve this problem or another way how to implement my goal.

Comment: Question need more detailis

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of [QT "Could not find the Qt platform plugin "xcb" "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62391587/qt-could-not-find-the-qt-platform-plugin-xcb)

As you can see from the error message, QT is missing something called "xcb," so you'll need to install that as well as some other dependencies of QT for linux.

From the post linked:

> `sudo apt install make g++ pkg-config libgl1-mesa-dev libxcb*-dev libfontconfig1-dev libxkbcommon-x11-dev python libgtk-3-dev`

After installing those and restarting your program, QT should start working fine.

Comment: also welcome to stack overflow! hope i helped

Comment: Thanks for your respond! I find that the problem appears when bot starts by systemd. When bot starts from console all works fine.